# Can't deploy new version of published Google apps script app with Rest API

Tags: google-apps-script

When trying to use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/update to update an existing deployment with a new version in clasp cli (https://github.com/google/clasp) I get error `Read-only deployments may not be modified.`

The deployment is a published/approved apps script project. So far I have worked around the problem by updating version manually in the GUI. Would be great if anyone knows how I can do that with the API.

Comment: Did you set the correct `versionNumber`? When I test this, if I set the `versionNumber` to `0`, or if I don't set it, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Archived deployments are set to read-only, they can't be modified or deleted.
you can find the solution in [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#redeploy_an_archived_deployment) about managing deployments:

> If you want to edit an archived deployment, you must redeploy it ...

If you need to deploy a new version then the solution is not to update the version of an existing deployment, but to make a new deployment with the new version.

[Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#create_a_version) says:

> A version is automatically created when you create a new deployment. You can also create a new version from an existing deployment ...